# How to ask KAFKA about it's status - number of consumers, etc.? Particularly when it's running in a docker container?

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

I am looking at how to get the information on the number of consumers from a Kafka server running in a docker container.

But I'll also take almost any info to help point me in a direction that is forward movement. I've been trying through Python ond URI requests, but I'm getting the feeling I need to get back to Java to ask Kafka questions on it's status?

In relation to the current threads I've seen, many handy scripts from $KAFKA_HOME are referenced but, *the configured systems I have access to do not have $KAFKA_HOME defined - nor do they have the contents of that directory. My world is a docker container without a CLI access.* So I haven't been able to apply the solutions requiring shell scripts or other tools from $KAFKA_HOME to my running system.

One of the things I have tried is a python script using requests.get(uri...)
where the uri looks like:
http://localhost:9092/connectors/

```
The code looks like:

  r = requests.get("http://%s:%s/connectors" % (config.parameters['kafkaServerIPAddress'],config.parameters['kafkaServerPort']))
    currentConnectors=r.json()
```

So far I get a "nobody's home at that address" response.

I'm really stuck and a pointer to something akin to "Beginners Guide to Getting KAFKA Monitoring Information" would be great. Also if there's a way to grab the helpful kafka shell scripts & tools, that would be great to - where do they come from?

*One last thing - I'm new enough to Kafka that I don't know what I don't know.*

Thanks.

Comment: Kafka Connect REST API will only tell you about Connect, not the brokers. Plus it runs on port 8083

Comment: _number of consumers_ - this doesn't exist as any metric

Comment: You should be able to install either a [Python-native Kafka client library](https://pypi.org/search/?q=kafka) or the Kafka CLI tools in your Dockerfile, even if you're not going to run the Kafka broker yourself.

Answer (score 0):

> running in a Docker container

That shouldn't matter, but Confluent maintains a few pages that go over how to configure the containers for monitoring

- https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/docker/operations/monitoring.html
- https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/kafka/monitoring.html

> number of consumers

Such a metric doesn't exist

> Python and URI requests

You appear to be using the `/connectors` endpoint of the Kafka Connect REST API (which runs on port 8083, not 9092). It is not a monitoring endpoint for brokers or non-Connect-API consumers

> way to grab the helpful kafka shell scripts & tools

https://kafka.apache.org/downloads > Binary downloads

You don't need container shell access, but you will need external network access, just as all clients outside of a container would.