# Kafka API - 404 errors on documented endpoints when trying to access Kafka API

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I am having difficulties with the Kafka REST API and I’m not sure what I misunderstand about it.

I’m using nodeJS and javascript to query the API - along with using cURL to manually check that the API commands are correct. I'll stick to the cURL commands for simplicity's sake.

Something that works as expected:

```
curl --silent -X GET http://<IP address>:8083/connectors
```

returns simply `'[  ]'` (an empty array)

Which I understand to mean I have no connectors installed - which is correct for the development system I am trying this on. When I use the same query on a production system I get a suitably verbose answer.

So the connectors API seems happy.

*But* then:

```
curl -X GET http://192.168.136.129:8090/kafka/v3/clusters/
```

returns:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.136.129 port 8090 after 2022 ms: Connection refused
```

And the other query from documentation (URL to kafka documentation referenced - Confluent REST Proxy 6.0: Putting Kafka to REST) to get cluster information isn’t working.

```
curl http://localhost:8082/kafka/v3/clusters
```

also returned “`404 not found`”

**The `rest-proxy` is up and running when I '`docker-compose ps`' it.**

The version information from the system (from `http::8083/`) is:

{
version: '6.0.0-ccs', commit: '17b744c31e00868b', kafka_cluster_id: 'AHSIbhcaRAmKkWV0lo1I4w'
}

I’m trying to put together a small command line app that returns status information of the kafka installation (monitoring information as it’s called in some of the confluent documents) and I thought the REST API would be efficient.

Comment: Connect is not related to the REST Proxy, so I dont understand the first half of the question. Also, port 8090 is not the same as 8082, and port 8083 is not the rest-proxy, so also confusing what you are really trying to connect to

Answer (score 0):

> The version information from the system (from http::8083/) is:

> `{ version: '6.0.0-ccs', commit: '17b744c31e00868b', kafka_cluster_id: 'AHSIbhcaRAmKkWV0lo1I4w' }`

That's the correct address and response for Kafka Connect API, not the REST Proxy. Unclear what port 8090 is for, or why you need to use an external IP address.

> I’m trying to put together a small command line app that returns status information of the kafka installation

You don't need REST for a command-line app. You can use `kafka-topics.sh --describe __consumer_offsets | head` as a basic "status" / health check if the broker is running.

> monitoring information

You can add the Prometheus JMX Exporter or Jolokia agent to get monitoring data over REST and integrate with the monitoring information mentioned by [my answer to your previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69981206/how-to-ask-kafka-about-its-status-number-of-consumers-etc-particularly-whe)

Comment: Where does kafka-topics.sh live? Is is part of the standard confluent installation? I can't seem to locate it.

Comment: Didn't find kafka-topics.sh but did find: 
https://medium.com/@TimvanBaarsen/apache-kafka-cli-commands-cheat-sheet-a6f06eac01b#471a 
which allowed me to get into a docker container and a kafka shell [appuser@kafka ~] - whereupon I found myself in somewhat over my head....

Comment: @Lindsay It's a script built into the Kafka installation, yes, and you need to use it to actually create any topic for your Kafka code to use... The script should be on the PATH of the broker container already (or you could just not use Docker, if you're "over your head" with it)

Comment: You can also use Nodejs to describe the cluster https://kafka.js.org/docs/admin#a-name-describe-cluster-a-describe-cluster